# Disable Outlook "Top Results" / "show most relevant search results on top" via PowerShell / Registry / Group Policy

Tags: microsoft-outlook, powershell, microsoft-office, windows-registry, group-policy

I am unable to find a way to disable the Microsoft Outlook search option "show most relevant search results on top" via a systematic / automated approach so that I can deploy this to all of our users.

The setting is located via in the GUI via the following:

***"File" -> "Options" -> "Search" -> "Show most relevant search results on top".***

What I have tried so far:

**Group Policy**

The most recent ADMX for configuring Microsoft 365 / Office etc does not seem to have an option to configure this:

https://admx.help/?Category=Office2016&Policy=outlk16.Office.Microsoft.Policies.Windows::L_HitHighlightingcolor

**Registry**

After inspecting the applications modifications to the registry via "Process Monitor" when setting the option via the GUI, I have then modified the following key to `0` of which had no impact.

`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Search\SearchTopResults`

Adding this key to the following location as per Christy's answer below also has no effect to outlook:

`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\outlook\Search\SearchTopResults`

**Office configuration Tool**

The office configuration tool also does not appear to show any possibility of disabling this option under "Application Prferences":

https://config.office.com/deploymentsettings

---

PS - the environment that this being tested in is connected to active directory with policies applied through an existing "group policy" deployment.

If anyone is able to give any insight on how to do this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my research on the below registry:
**Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\outlook\Search\SearchTopResults**

When the value of SearchTopResults is set to **1**, the "show most relevant search results on top" option is **selected**. On the other hand, when the value of SearchTopResults is set to **0**, the "show most relevant search results on top" option is **unselected**.
[image]

So it's suggested that you could try to open Registry Editor and locate the path (especially please note the **Policies** key), if the path can't be found, please try to manually create the path and values to check if there're any differences.

Comment: Thanks @Christy , unfortunately this is not successful, the key path didnt exist so I manually created this under the policies parent path as per your suggestion. I will update the question with this information.

Comment: Have you restarted Outlook after changing the registry?

Comment: Yes I tried the following combinations (1 - changing registry whilst Outlook was closed then starting outlook. 2 - changing registry whilst outlook was open and restarting the application.). Are you able to confirm if this is successful for you? It seems like changing the registry has no impact on outlook at all when I have tried.

Comment: It's suggested that you could go back and check if you have changed the value of the registry successfully. On the other hand, does this registry work on other computers?

Comment: I will be testing this on a system that has not been added to the domain to see if its group policy that is preventing the change from being possible.

Comment: I can confirm that the registry edits (both the `policies` & direct `SOFTWARE` path previously specified) have no impact to a system not connected to the domain.

Comment: Does other registry work in your computer? And does your administrator make any restrictions on the registry or anything like that?

Comment: I can confirm that other registry entries in `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Preferences` i.e `ShowBcc` functions as expected. I am the administrator / IT Manager, there is no one above me and I can confirm that there is nothing in place that should prevent this from working. As per one of my previous comments could you confirm the solution you have provided works for yourself?

Comment: Of course! Based on my test, when i changed the registry and restarted Outlook, the box in front of that option changes. It should be noted that the registry does not ash that option, but only changes whether the box in front of the option is checked.